# I am looking a journal named Moscow: Metallurgiya from 1971. Any Leads how I can find this journal?

Tags: journals

I need this journal for my master thesis research as some of the relevant papers I am using have this journal as a reference. I need the edition from 1971. I have tried various Russian research sites but I could not find this. Any leads would be really appreciated.

Comment: Ask your librarian, helping with such problems is their job.

Comment: Please provide the full reference. I am not from this research area, but speak Russian. A quick hinted me, it's a publisher name (residing in Moscow), but not a journal.

Comment: A couple of references I've been able to find so far indicate that the journal going by this (Metallurgiya) name in Russia would be Acta Metallurgica [1](http://195.19.135.90/WEBIRBIS/CGI/irbis64r_11/cgiirbis_64.exe?LNG=&C21COM=S&I21DBN=INJOUR&P21DBN=INJOUR&S21FMT=fullwebr&S21ALL=%3C.%3ER%3D53$%3C.%3E&Z21ID=&S21SRW=AVHEAD&S21SRD=&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21CNR=20) [2](http://library.vstu.ru/docs/periodical/Metallurgy.pdf). As Oleg has pointed out, you've probably confused the journal name with the publisher.

Comment: @Lodinn - was Acta translated into Russian?

Comment: Editing your question to include one or more of the papers you're looking for may be useful. Some Russian journals or articles were translated into English by the US government, for instance.

Comment: Wasn't Leonid Brezhnev a Metallurgy graduate?  I wonder whether there's some sort of political satire at work that we don't get.

Comment: @JonCuster Probably, but it's almost certainly irrelevant: after digging a bit more, I'm nearly 100% sure Oleg is right. Take this example of bibliographic reference "Владимиров В.И. Физическая природа разрушения металлов. - М.: Металлургия, 1984.": it's a book titled "Физическая природа разрушения металлов" and published in 1984 by the Metallurgiya publisher. Or "Браун Н. - в кн.: Микропластичность: Пер. с англ. - М.: Металлургия, 1972." seems to be referring to the 1972 translation of Brown, N. (1968). Microplasticity. In *Advan. Mater. Res.* (Vol. 2, p. 45).

Comment: @DanielHatton not exactly, no. He's worked a number of years in metallurgy though.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I am looking for three articles. At least this is what is understood. I can share them here. Maybe this helps for the search. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @OlegLobachev

Чекмарев А.П., Спиридонов Н.П., Куцыгин Я.Д. Аналитическое определение технологических коэффициентов влияния натяжения и различных возмущений на параметры непрерывной прокатки. Сб. Прокатное производство, ток ХХХУ. М.: Металлургия 1971. – 242 с.

Чекмарев А.П., Чернобривенко Ю.С., Куцыгин М.Д., Барвинов В.П. Расчет натяжения при непрерывной прокатке. Сб. Прокатное производство, ток ХХХУ. М.: Металлургия 1971. – 242 с.

Comment: @OlegLobachev

Чекмарев А.П., Куцов Ю.Г., Теряев В.А. Исследования давления металла на валки, крутящих моментов и расчет натяжения на непрерывном проволочном стане 250. Сб. Прокатное производство, ток ХХХУ. М.: Металлургия 1971. – 242 с.

Comment: Well, I have found this like this: https://search.rsl.ru/ru/record/01007068331, but no immediate PDFs. But it a series of a publisher, not a journal. Those are books.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Any idea where I can find these books?

I tried to find it at my university library, but they are not able to find it since it is in Russian

Comment: Try asking someone from the similar area in Russia...